# Unknown version of Tomcat was specified in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to add latest tomcat-7.0.42 in my eclipse. Probably eclipse tomcat server adapter 7 only supports tomcat version upto 7.0.12 ..

[image]

So please help me how can I configure my eclipse with tomcat-7.0.42

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You are specifying tomcat source directory.

You need to specify tomcat binary installation root directory, also known as CATALINA_HOME.

Usually, this is where you untar `apache-tomcat-7.0.42.tar.gz` file.

Comment: I installed using brew, /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat7/7.0.57/libexec/ worked for me.

Comment: Amazing ... Thank you : @Alexander Pogrebnyak

Comment: I used `sudo catalina start` - then typed `echo $CATALINA_HOME` then stopped catalina with `sudo catalina stop`

Comment: I had java 8 and tomcat 8 installed in my ubuntu. This tomcat path works for me `/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.52`

Comment: In my case, it was related with the permission of folders under the tomcat directory. Due to that eclipse couldn't read required information from `conf/` and `lib/` folders. Changed permission recursively with `chmod -R 777 tomcat/ ` in Ubuntu

Answer (score 28):

This happened to me because Tomcat was still in the process of downloading (`Download and Install`). The message disappeared after a few minutes.

The eclipse window should really have some type of progress indicator showing download status.

Comment: Yeah, the dialog has no window, but the lower right corner of the main IDE window has a progress bar.

Comment: This should be the marked right answer for this question. :)

Comment: Seems like this is just a UI problem - the operation doesn't block, but doesn't provide clear feedback that anything is going on.

Answer (score 19):

To recognise your Tomcat installation folder, Eclipse is scanning for the following files:

```
conf/catalina.policy
conf/server.xml
conf/web.xml
conf/context.xml
conf/tomcat-users.xml
conf/catalina.policy
conf/catalina.properties
lib/catalina.jar
```

so make sure you're pointing to the right place and have the right read permissions.

E.g.

- OS X (if installed via `brew`), it's: `/usr/local/opt/tomcat/libexec`
- Linux/Ubuntu: see: [Tomcat and Eclipse Integration Error](https://askubuntu.com/q/435283/78223)

Comment: In my case I don't have read permissions to `conf` and `lib` directory so I get this error. A bit of  `chmod o+r -R {conf,lib}` helped ;)

Answer (score 18):

For LINUX the installation directory for Tomcat 7 is:
/usr/share/tomcat7

Please use this configuration.

More here:
http://gridlab.dimes.unical.it/lackovic/eclipse-tomcat-ubuntu-jersey/

Comment: Thanks that was the solution.

Comment: You are gienee for me!!

Answer (score 13):

I know this is and oldie but i had this issue recently with the latest versions of Tomcat and Eclipse on Windows 10.

It was a permissions issue. All i had to do was navigate to the Tomcat install directory and open the folder. I was prompted to access the folder as an Administrator.

After this the versions were recognised by Eclipse and I could add the new runtime.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same error and resolved it by giving enough permissions to the folder. I gave full permissions by (you can try limited permissions which is enough for eclipse to run tomcat)

```
sudo chmod -R 777 apache-tomcat-8.5.33/
```

FYI, I encountered this error on my mac, but I think it should be same for ubuntu system too.

Answer (score 9):

I am on MacOS and installed tomcat using homebrew, Following path fixed my problem

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/9.0.14/libexec
```

Answer (score 6):

As soon as you provide the directory where Tomcat needs to be installed and click ok you can notice download and installation starts in the progress tab of Eclipse.

[image]

Let the process complete.The error will automatically disappear.

[image]

**Note: It is not mandatory to name your folder `CATALINA_HOME`. I have tested this with windows. Cannot assert the same for Linux but IMO same rule should apply.**

Comment: So this is UI fault on eclipse side. Not very productive/friendly. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 15 and your answer helped. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

Probably, you are trying to point the tomcat directory having the source folder. Please download the tomcat binary version from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) .For Linux environments, there you can find .zip and .tar.gz files under core section. Please download and extract them. after that, if you point this extracted directory, eclipse will be able to identify the tomcat version. Eclipse was not able to find the version of tomcat, since the directory you pointed out didn't contain the conf folder. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Just in case...
Apache Tomcat 8.5.X is not compatible with Apache Tomcat 8.0 server selection in eclipse. And it gives this error.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Window -> preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments"

Remove the existing servers they might not have downloaded completely.

Add new Server

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Users,

Use the Tomcat Service Installer from the Apache tomcat downloads page. You will get a .exe file. which Installs the service for windows. It will usually install Apache tomcat at "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0" and its easily recognized in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Having installed tomcat with brew the solution for me was:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/<your_version>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I used wrong directory, the right one is lib exec and my path:
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat@7/7.0.96/libexec

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to the source directory. You can run a build by running ant from that same directory, then add '\output\build' to the end of the installation directory path.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the access of the tomcat installation path(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0) wasn't available with the current user.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is already duplicated with: "You need to specify tomcat binary installation root directory"

Answer (score 0):

Since this is evidently happening on Linux, this would be because your dev user might not have read access to Tomcat's installation directory. That's because Tomcat's installation directory (let's say it is pointed to by `CATALINA_HOME`) is owned by `tomcat:tomcat` while your dev user is something that's neither `tomcat` nor one that belongs to the `tomcat` group. Therefore Eclipse fails to read `${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/catalina.policy`.

The following should fix the permission issue:

```
sudo find ${CATALINA_HOME} -type d -exec chmod o+rx {} \;
```

Why do we need the execute bits? Because to traverse a directory and reach its descendants, you need execute permissions. In your case, if `CATALINA_HOME` isn't yet set, replace the actual installation directory (`/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-<version>` maybe?) in the above.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows

Just open the (tomcat xx.x) folder once and check if you can see all other root folders while selecting folder.
Sometimes windows wont give access to this folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).