# Not able to add tomcat in eclipse oxygen 2017

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat

I am trying to add Tomcat but Next button is Freeze.

[image]

I have deleted file org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs, but file **org.eclipse.jst/server.tomcat.core.prefs** is not present. I followed same steps as suggested in 
[How to add Tomcat Server in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046871/how-to-add-tomcat-server-in-eclipse)
After that I tried to add Tomcat server, but still not successful.

I am using eclipse oxygen. Please find the screenshot.
[image: Eclipse Oxygen]

Ways I tried to add tomcat :-

1. Went to Servers --> Selected Apache --> Tomcat v7.0
2. Eclipse --> Preferences --> Server --> Runtime Environments --> Add --> Apache --> Tomcat v 7.0

Comment: How do we verify you're actually using Oxygen? What steps were taken to have Tomcat there?

Comment: @nitind I have updated screenshot and steps taken to add server.

Comment: See if the answers to this SO post help: [Unknown version of Tomcat was specified with tomcat-7.0.42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745834/unknown-version-of-tomcat-was-specified-with-tomcat-7-0-42). However, you are using an old version of Oxygen, so you might want to update Eclipse first.

Comment: Does the Progress View or lower right-hand corner of the workbench window show it still downloading?

Comment: I am updating eclipse. Earlier it was not showing still downloading.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I have finally resolved the issue. Steps I followed to resolve it are :- 1) Went to the folder where I have unzipped tomcat. 2) Go to /bin folder 3) Converted all .sh files into executable files using chmod +x *.sh 4) Ran script to start and stop Tomcat (./startup.sh & ./shutdown.sh). 5) Now its adding Tomcat in eclipse.