# Adding tomcat to eclipse: Unknown version of tomcat version 8.5 windows10 specified error .?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey

I'm not able to add version 8.5 to my eclipse IDE (2020-03). Even if I try a different version and go for download and install it's showing access denied error after installing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745834/unknown-version-of-tomcat-was-specified-with-tomcat-7-0-42

Comment: Show us the error.